# Nested for loop fails to loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, nested, nested-loops

I have written the following nested for loop which is supposed to iterate over the data frame, df, and create 1 in the column a, if the row q has a in it. Generally, for columns a,b and c, if the entry in column q matches the column name, columns a,b and c should indicate that by having one.

As I am not able to describe it well, here is a piece of code to illustrate what I mean.

At this moment, the resulting df only has an 1 in column c,in the respective third row, but not for column a or b.

```
    df = data.frame(q=c("a","b","c"),a=c(0,0,0),b=c(0,0,0),c=c(0,0,0))

    for (x in nrow(df)) {
  for (y in ncol(df)) { 
if (colnames(df[y]) == df$q[x]) { 
  df[x,y] = 1} 
}}
```

[A picture of the intended output (whereas the red "1s" do not appear at this moment:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIFHY.png)

Moreover, the actual dataframe I am working on is roughly 100 000 rows and 100 columns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because for (x in nrow(df)) means x = 3, cause nrow(df) returns 3. You should write like this: 
for (x in 1 : nrow(df)), which return 1 2 3.

```
for (x in 1 : nrow(df)) {
  for (y in 1 : ncol(df)) { 
    if (colnames(df[y]) == df$q[x]) { 
      df[x,y] = 1} 
  }
}
```

Now the df is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option to avoid the loop.

```
library(tidyr)       
library(dplyr)
gather(df, key, value, -q) %>%
 mutate(value = if_else(q == key, 1, 0)) %>%
 spread(key, value)
 #  q a b c
 #1 a 1 0 0
 #2 b 0 1 0
 #3 c 0 0 1
```

`gather` columns `a`, `b`, `c` and then compare the newly created column `key` with `q`. If the respective values are the same, assign `1`, else `0`.